# Android webview: javascript method count

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview, cross-platform

I am developing an Android library for cross-platform development with JavaScript and I have encountered problem with JavaScript method count - like Android multidex problem. That is, if a JavaScript object with around 64k methods or more is loaded into a WebView, it will be missing random methods. Does anybody have the same problem and know a solution for it?

Comment: Please try the edited answer below.

Comment: So, now i can see java methods count. How this can help me?

Comment: It will help you to overcome the multidex problem. Did the below edited solution helped you to resolve the issue you were facing previously?

Comment: Nope. Multidex already enabled in my app. The problem is with javascript method count, not java. Javascript not included into dex files, it is just loaded into webview as a webpage.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in app/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral() // or jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount:dexcount-gradle-plugin:0.8.2'
  }
}

// make sure this line comes *after* you apply the Android plugin
apply plugin: 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nope. This will work for java method count, not for javascript.